# How to save any changes to my local data in Backbone.js app?

Tags: backbone.js

I'm doing a local Backbone.js app and use a local folder named data to put the initial data. And in my Backbone.router, I use ajax to get the initial data as follows:

```
p = $.ajax({
        url: 'data/todolist.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {},
        success: function(data) {
            var approuter = new AppRouter({data: data});
            Backbone.history.start();
        }
    })
```

And the `initialize` method in my `AppRouter` is as follows:

```
initialize: function(options){
        this._data = options.data;
        this._todos = new TodosCollection(options.data);
        this._length = this._todos.length;
        this._index = new CategoriesView({collection: this._todos});
    },
```

In my app, every time I create, delete and update an item in my Backbone.View, I will use `this.model.destroy()`, `this.collection.add()` or `this.model.set()` to update my model and collection. But it seems that it doesn't save these changes to my initial data, which is 'todolist.json' above. When I refresh the whole page, the app still shows the initial data. What I want to do is the data file will get updated every time some changes happen in my View. So how should I achieve this?

One more question: What if I want to use localStorage to keep these data? Don't I need to use ajax call in my router? I just use a `Backbone.Collection.fetch()` method in Router's `initialize` method at the very beginning and after the app gets started, the localStorage will update the data automatically every time I use `this.model.destroy()`, `this.collection.add()` or `this.model.set()`?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to write back the modified data to the .json file, or do you want to use the .json file as initial data and after that use Local Storage/IndexedDB/Web SQL/... for persistence? Anyway, Backbone is pretty lightweight and doesn't support either of these functionality out-of-the-box. You've to write this yourself, or find a plugin which does this.

Writing to Local Files should be possible in HTML5 apps usign the [FileSystem API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/), but it could be tricky to get it to work in all browsers. Besides, you can only read/write files in a special sandboxed section of the filesystem.

For Local Storage, have a look at the backbone-localstorage.js plugin. The Todo example app included with Backbone is also using this plugin. From the top of my head, basically, you need to override the fetch and sync methods of your model.